# Starting an application in the background in Unity

Tags: process, unity-game-engine, background

Anybody knows how to start an application in the background (Using C#)  when pressing on a button in Unity? I looked everywhere but I could only find the Process.Start() way to execute external application. That unfortunately turns the focus to it, which is something I don't want.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hey, I know you chose my answer but I have a question. Did you mean that you want to make Unity continue running in the background even if the game/editor/application is not focused or you want to start another application in the background? I am confused and I want to make sure that my answer is what you want.

Comment: @Programmer, I really am not sure what I was trying to do back then. This is quite an old post but if I chose your answer then it means it worked for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use

```
Application.runInBackground = true;
```

to make your Application run in the background. Set it to false to make it NOT run in the background.

```
Application.runInBackground = false;
```

Comment: That makes Unity run in the background, not the secondary process, which seems to be what OP is asking.

Comment: @Junuxx Just saw this now. He never said anything about secondary process. I guess this is what he wants since it worked for him.

Comment: He definitely did. He says he wants to "start an application in the background" *from Unity*. He also says he tried `Process.Start()`, which is for starting external processes. That's not what didn't work though. What he asked for help with is that this external process launched in the foreground. So either OP managed to phrase his question incredibly poorly, or he accepted an answer than doesn't actually solve his problem at all.

Comment: @Junuxx I really want to know about this. I will ask him in the question comment section.

Comment: @Junuxx He couldn't remember but said if he chose my answer, it means that it worked for him. I think that's what he meant. Unity freezes when not focused if you don't use the code above. The way he phrased it is the problem.

Comment: I guess so, huh! Props for going the extra mile, a year later, +1

Answer (score 0):

If you press a button in Unity App, you'll lose a focus of the current app.

But, 
1) You can execute other android app using PackageManager API.
(Unity can call android's api using AndroidJavaClass)

```
Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.package.address");
startActivity(launchIntent);
```

2) Once it is executed, you can reorder among current task stack apps.

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, MyMainActivity.class);
i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
startActivity(i);
```

So, I think you could try some trick. 
A can execute B, then B gave back its focus to A immediately.(some flickering)
Or A execute B, and then A can take back its focusing from B in the background.

Comment: Why do you assume this is about Unity on Android?

Answer (score 0):

If you call `process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()`, then you probably need to switch to [`BeginOutputReadLine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.beginoutputreadline?view=netframework-4.8) and [`OutputDataReceived`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.outputdatareceived?view=netframework-4.8) so that Unity doesn't block while reading output from your process.

Making that change and using `StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true` allowed me to keep focus on Unity.